# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<UserInterests>' shared preferences in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, sharedpreferences

In my app i want store List of object in shared preferences but when I get that data from shared preferences I get Unhandled Exception:

> type `List<dynamic>` is not a subtype of type `List<UserInterests>`

exception and didn't get the data

Here is my code

```
static void addInterests(List<UserInterests> interests) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString('interstsArray', jsonEncode(interests));
  }

  static Future<List<UserInterests>> getInterests() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    List<UserInterests> interests = jsonDecode(prefs.getString('interstsArray'));
    return interests;
  }

static void logoutUserSF() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove("interstsArray");
  }
```

Error occur in getInterests function in second line jsonDecode, Give some suggestion how to do it

Answer (score 1):

`jsonDecode()` converts the `String` to a `List<dynamic>`, it's not aware of the `UserInterests` type. You have to write a function/constructor to convert it yourself, something like :

```
UserInterests.fromJson(List<dynamic> json){
  firstMember = json['firstMember'];
  secondMember = json['secondMember'];
}
```

You can then use it like :

```
List<UserInterests> interests = [
  for(var json in jsonDecode(prefs.getString('interstsArray')))
     UserInterests.fromJson(json),
];
```

Comment: in my userIntersts class i have
factory UserInterests.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$UserInterestsFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserInterestsToJson(this); 

So I put that code in here?

Comment: If you already have a generated one, then try using it and fixing it if it fails (because sometimes types are not inferred correctly by generators). Or just rewrite it I guess, your choice :)